# Show selected data as array value instead of string

Tags: php, sql, arrays, string

I'm trying to put data from my database into seperate arrays within another array. This works but when I'm trying to fetch the 'user_id' information, it only shows one number so it works like a string. How can I get it to work like an array and get the entire user_id?

```
$fetch = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM spotify_userdata");

$return_arr = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $return_arr[] = array(
        $row_array['user_id'] = $row['user_id'],
        $row_array['name'] = $row['name'],
        $row_array['artists'] = $row['artists'],
    );
}

$user = json_encode($return_arr[0]);

echo $user[2];
```

This code returns 1 so it show the third number of the user_id. How can I get it to show the entire user_id like this: 111434343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many things in your code that's wrong:

1. Remove the last array item's comma
2. Change

> $return_arr = [];

To

> $return_arr = array();

3.Add:

```
$row_array = array()
```

at the begginning of all that code

At the end your code must be like this:

```
$fetch = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM spotify_userdata");

$row_array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $return_arr = array(
        $row_array['user_id'] = $row['user_id'],
        $row_array['name'] = $row['name'],
        $row_array['artists'] = $row['artists'],
    );
}

$user = json_encode($return_arr[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Some stupid mistakes in my coding. Works great now.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you should use:

```
echo $user['user_id'];
```

But the real problem is - where is **$row_array** initialized?!?

And even bigger problem - why use "=" inside array creation in the while ... it seems to me that "=>" would fit better, don't you think?